# Multiplying expressions within a list of pure functions

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

Let's say I have a list of pure functions that are nice algebraic expressions: say

```
l = {(#1 - 1)&, (#1^2 + #1)&, (#1^3 - 1)&}
```

What's an easy way to get a pure function that will give the product of these expressions?  For example, in the above I'd like to get a function f with

```
f = (#1 - 1)(#1^2 + #1)(#1^3 - 1)&
```

I've tried `(Times @@ Identity @@@ l)&`, but this just gives `(#1 - 1)(#1^2 + #1)(#1^3 - 1)`.  Essentially, it seems my difficulty is converting a `List` of `Function` expressions to a `Function[Times[...]]` expression, and I can't see how to "strip off" the functions without messing up the referencing of the `Slot[1]` expressions inside.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @PinguinDirk, I was presuming that the OP wanted to keep it as a pure function.

Comment: I misread anyway, actually I am not too sure what the OP actually wants... maybe `Function[x, Times @@ Through[l[x]]]`? But thanks for pointing that out, @Jonathan Shock

Comment: @PinguinDirk Your suggestion gives what I want as well; the use of `Through` is clever.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mapping *First* over your list will strip off the *Function* head.  Then multiply them together with *Apply[Times...* and finally *Apply[Function...* makes the result a pure function.  Use the final *Apply* so the argument to *Function* is evaluated first as *Function* has the attribute *HoldAll*.

```
Apply[Function,{Apply[Times, Map[First,l]]}]
```

Gives...

```
(-1+#1) (#1+#1^2) (-1+#1^3)&
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works perfectly!

Comment: This can also be written: `Function @@ {Times @@ First /@ l}`

Answer (score 8):

Here is another option:

```
l = {(#1 - 1) &, (#1^2 + #1) &, (#1^3 - 1) &};

Thread[Times @@ l, Function]
```

> ```
> (#1 - 1) (#1^3 - 1) (#1^2 + #1) &
> ```

This has the benefit of not evaluating the body of the functions.  For example:

```
l = {(#1 - 1) &, (#1^2 + #1) &, (Print["!"]; #1^3 - 1) &};

Thread[Times @@ l, Function]
```

> ```
> (#1 - 1) (Print["!"]; #1^3 - 1) (#1^2 + #1) &
> ```

Note that the `Print` statement remains.  Compare with:

```
Function @@ {Times @@ First /@ l}
```

> !
>
> ```
> (-1 + #1) (#1 + #1^2) (-1 + #1^3) &
> ```