# Pattern Match and Replace Expression involving Pure Function

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

Let's say I have an expression that in held form contains a pointer to a function.

```
expr = Hold[2*{"FUNCTION1"} + 5];
```

`{"FUNCTION1"}` references a pure function or combination of other functions that are verbose and would be redundant to retype. For an example, let's say the function is:

```
func = #^2 &
```

In later calculations, I want to define a new function that uses `expr` with the referenced function substituted:

```
newfunc = ReleaseHold[expr /. {"FUNCTION1"} :> func]
```

> `5 + 2 (#1^2 &)`

However, this is not what I'm after as trying to evaluate `newfunc` reveals:

```
newfunc[5]
```

> `(5 + 2 (#1^2 &))[5]`

What I'm really after is

```
(5 + 2*#1^2) &[5]
```

> `55`

So, is there a pattern format that can be used to correctly splice in the pure function. This needs to be general as `expr` won't always have the same form.

Comment: Related: [(28064)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28064/121)

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  I am curious to know how (where) you are using this method.

Comment: @MrWizard I'd be glad to show you, but it'll require something more substantial than a comment box to explain. I still have your email if you're that interested.

Comment: Go ahead; thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Email sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to recall a similar question but I cannot find it now.  Anyway a key detail is that the body of the function presumably should not be evaluated, meaning e.g. `func = Print[#^2] &` should still work.

Here is one approach:

```
expr = Hold[2*{"FUNCTION1"} + 5];

func = Print[#^2] &;

newfunc = Function @@ expr /. {"FUNCTION1"} -> Hold @@ func // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> 2 Print[#1^2] + 5 &
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these other approaches will be useful for you pointer to function problem :

### 1.`expr[x_] := 2*func[x] + 5`

You can now for example always use `expr` but switch `func` to your needs. For example :

```
func = Sin ; expr[hello]
func = #^2 &; {expr[hello], expr[5]}
```

return

> 5 + 2 Sin[hello]
>   {5 + 2 hello^2, 55}

But if you really need to **create explicitly a new function**, you can do :

```
func = #^3 &;
expr2[x_] = expr[x]
```

> 5 + 2 x^3

```
(*check*)
expr2[1]
(* 7 *)
```

or if you prefer the `Function` approach :

```
func = Tan;
expr3 = Function[x, Evaluate@expr@x]
```

> Function[x, 5 + 2 Tan[x]]

```
(*check*)
expr3[2]
(*5 + 2 Tan[2]*)
```

### 2. `fexpr[func_][x_] := 2*func[x] + 5`

This approach is even more useful I guess.

Then for example :

```
fexpr[Sin][10]
```

> 5 + 2 Sin[10]

```
fexpr[#^2 &][5]
```

> 55

```
Plot[fexpr[#^2 &][x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

If you need to **create new functions**, then for example :

```
f1 = fexpr[Cos][#] &
```

> fexpr[Cos][#1] &

```
f1[Pi/3]
```

> 6

In this previous case you see that `f1` is defined as a function of `fexpr`. This way, you can track what was your input function. But maybe this is exactly what you don't want, then you can do instead :

```
f2 = Function[x, Evaluate@fexpr[Tan][x]]
```

> Function[x, 5 + 2 Tan[x]]

Here `f2` is not a function of `fexpr` anymore (no more traces how the function was created).

```
(*check*)
f2[10]
(*5 + 2 Tan[10]*)
```

I haven't check, but there is probably here a lot of other posts and answers for this kind of problems.

Comment: I don't know if this is applicable to the OP's "template" code but it is good information so +1.  Releated: [(7999)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7999/121)